# feed the result of job as input for another job spring batch

Tags: parallel-processing, spring-batch

Here is want I what to do. Create three jobs: job1, job2 & job3. job1 reads an xml file and divides what it read into 2 junks. These junks will then be used as input for job2 and job3 which are going to process (read) them in parallel and print their respective lectures on the console.
I wanted to know if that is even possible.

Comment: Do you really need 3 jobs instead of 1 job with 3 steps?

Comment: @Dmitry it just an approach that I thought. Btw is the above scenario possible with steps?